# OpenACC PGI compiler GPU support

Tags: pgi

Which GPUs support PGI compiler (OpenACC and cuda unified memory)? Kepler, Maxwell, Pascal? What about GTX 670, 770, 970 ? M-series(for notebooks)? It is true that support only for tesla and all pascal series?

Answer (score 2):

While exact devices PGI supports will change depending on the PGI compiler version, for PGI 18.10, we support NVIDIA GPU devices with compute capabilities 3.0 to 7.0. (See: https://www.pgroup.com/resources/docs/18.10/x86/pgi-release-notes/index.htm#compute-cap)

Officially, PGI supports the Tesla product line.  But by support we're meaning the devices that we've done extensive testing on.  In practice, other NVIDIA devices such as the GeForce and Quadro products that use the same compute capabilities should work as well.